# Regex to match text after a given string excluding the character itself

Tags: javascript, regex

I got this regex

`(?<=token=)(.*?)(?=;)`

and on the https://regex101.com it says that

> ? The preceding token is not quantifiable

I'm trying to get string after `token=` excluding it and before first `;` excluding it too

`string = [ 'nginx/1.15.2',
  'Fri, 22 Feb 2019 22:39:19 GMT',
  'application/json',
  '76',
  'close',
  [ 'token=fCMNSX6y85W.7jOzwvpp8GQ; Secure; HttpOnly; expires=Wed, 21 Oct 2099 04:24:00 GMT' ],
  'content-type,cache-control,pragma,x-request-id',
  'true' ] '`

if I'm using this regex `token=(.*?)(?=;)`

I'm getting `token=fCMNSX6y85W.7jOzwvpp8GQ`

so, all I need from this string is `fCMNSX6y85W.7jOzwvpp8GQ`

Comment: Just split the result with `=` and take the first index. lookbehinds is included in JS recently so it is not available on all platform till now

Comment: If you want to use regexp - just use 'token=(.*?);' https://regex101.com/r/Ng8jRS/1 to get first match.

Comment: With pattern `token=(.*?)(?=;)` your value is in the first capturing group. You may also try `token=([^;]+)` and your value is in the first capturing group as well https://regex101.com/r/X6RrWq/1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value in the pattern `token=(.*?)(?=;)` is in the first capturing group.

You could simplify that pattern to `token=([^;]+)` capturing in a group matching not a semicolon.

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/LFpLPO/1)

```js
var s = `string = [ 'nginx/1.15.2',
  'Fri, 22 Feb 2019 22:39:19 GMT',
  'application/json',
  '76',
  'close',
  [ 'token=fCMNSX6y85W.7jOzwvpp8GQ; Secure; HttpOnly; expires=Wed, 21 Oct 2099 04:24:00 GMT' ],
  'content-type,cache-control,pragma,x-request-id',
  'true' ] '`;

var pattern = /token=([^;]+)/;
console.log(s.match(pattern)[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there

`token=(.*)(?=;)` will capture the token in the *capturing group* `(.*)`. Depending on which command/scripting language you use you can use a backreference to get the *capturing group* value.

If you're using JS it'll be something like this

```
var re = /token=(.*)(?=;)/
var found = 'token=fCMNSX6y85W.7jOzwvpp8GQ; Secure'.match(re);
if (found) {
    console.log(found[1])
}
```

Note `found[1]` is the first capturing group of the match.

https://jsfiddle.net/ogj4xpLc/2/

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Find

```
^string.+\n.+\n.+\n.+\n.+\n(.+)\n.+\n.+
```

Replace

```
$1
```

**Step2**

Find

```
.*token=(.*?);.*
```

Replace

```
$1\n
```